# JBehave - Examples table is executing comments

Tags: jbehave

When I execute the following in JBehave:

```
When I GET '<foo>' ACCEPT '<bar>'
Then I expect status <someStatus>
Then I expect response body <someBody>
Examples:
|foo|bar|someStatus|someBody|
|blah|blah|blah|blah|


!-- DELETE
```

It seems that the 'Examples:' takes in the comments (!-- DELETE) as part of the table, thus giving me invalid character errors.

```
Example: {foo=!-- DELETE, bar=, someStatus=, someBody=}
When I GET '!-- DELETE' ACCEPT '' (FAILED)
(java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character...
```

If I remove the comments the test runs without errors.

I would like to keep the comments after the table, how would I go about that?

Answer (score 2):

Try to use `|--` separator

Source: http://jbehave.org/reference/stable/faq.html

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, it seems like a JBehave bug for me in the table parser.

In our case there was something like this causing the same issue:

```
|foo |bar |someStatus|someBody|
|blah|blah|blah      |blah    |

!-- Scenario: commented out stuff
!-- Meta:
!-- @commentedMeta stuff
!-- etc.
```

As Karloss suggested, it was enough to use the `|--` instead of `!--` for the first comment to make the table work corretly, i.e.:

```
|foo |bar |someStatus|someBody|
|blah|blah|blah      |blah    |
|-- Scenario: commented out stuff    <== Note the change here in the first char!
!-- Meta:
!-- @commentedMeta stuff
!-- etc.
```